# New Pub/Sub topic w.r.t devices in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iot

I would like to create new pub/sub topic for devices just like we have config and command topic in GCP IoT Core.

I know about config and command topic in GCP.
e.g.

/devices/{device-id}/config

i would like to create a new topic just like this e.g.

/devices/{device-id}/Topic1
/devices/{device-id}/Topic2
and so on so only specific device can subscribe to it..

is it possible in GCP?

Comment: Is it only for the config? What's your use case? Why do you need this?

Comment: i need it for the some individual messages. like e.g. if i have 10 devices and i would like to send some message to 3 of them. how can i do that? and  i would like to do it from my cloud function..

Comment: If you have to send 3 messages, send them to the topic with the correct `device-id`. Why do you need to have several topics?

Comment: So that means if i have created a topic in pub/sub name e.g. Topic1. Then i can send message to each of the devices with devices/device_id/Topic1?

Comment: Ok, understood!!! But not possible.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any other solution to send messages to the device ?

Comment: Are you looking to publish on a GCP Pub/Sub topic and have a corresponding device be sent a command?  Remember, when we talk about Cloud IoT, there are two distinct concepts of "topic" ... we have MQTT topics and GCP Pub/Sub topics.  In your question, I am having trouble distinguishing "which" class of topic you are describing.

Comment: I would like to communicate with device using that Pub/sub topic. I already have Pub/Sub topics which publishes telemetry to the cloud but i want to do the otherway around to send data from cloud to the device. Its the same like config and commands topics but can i make my own topic to send data to the device?